# how to emit.to a socket.io room from within express route

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following code structure:

**/app.js**

```
var user = require('./server/routes/api/user');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
require('./server/sockets/base')(io);
```

I know I can emit events the following way (tested and works)

```
io.to("someroom").emit("news", "news");
```

Problem is, I want to be able to emit the event from my route file, which doesn't have access to the io object.

**/routes/api/user.js**

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
 // HERE I WANT TO EMIT THE EVENT BY USING io.to("someroom").emit("news", "news");
 // I TRIED req.socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' }); without luck
}
```

What would be the easiest way to emit with this folder structure?

Comment: as far I know you can't you are using a connection over tpc  but mixing https requests and sockets calls is not going to work.

Comment: @jack.the.ripper maybe he just wants to notify the room when someone logs in with HTTP. Have you tried exporting io and requiring it from the other file?

Comment: @liadmat I tried something like that got a lot of issues trying to do any socket operation inside a web request, if you have a solid reference of how to do it I'd like to take a peak, cheers!

Comment: @jack.the.ripper, I've added an answer

Comment: what happens in my app is that a user sets his current location and my node.js server stores that location. Based on that user position, my node server+mongodb return a couple of nearby places and I want to broadcast a message to those nearby places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route needs the `io` object, so you'll have to pass it as a parameter.

In user.js:

```
module.exports = function (io) {

    // all of this router's configurations

    router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
        io.to('someroom').emit('news', 'news');
    });

    return router;

}
```

When you use the route, give it a reference to `io`:

```
app.use(..., user(io));
```

Comment: So far, this breaks my routes, but I'm looking into it

Comment: Can't seem to shake of the error "Invalid HTTP status code 404" I get on all my user routes.

Comment: Solved it, my 404 route was loaded before my users route. Thanks for the answer, this solved my problem !

Answer (score 2):

```
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
app.set('io', io);
```

and then in the router

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  req.app.get('io').to('someroom').emit('news', 'news');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just export the socket and require it in any file you want to use it from.

**/socket.js**

```
var server = require('./app.js');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
module.exports = io;
```

**/app.js**

```
module.exports = server;
var user = require('./server/routes/api/user');
var io = require('./socket.js');
require('./server/sockets/base')(io);
```

**/routes/api/user.js**

```
var io = require('../../../socket.js');
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
    io.to("someroom").emit("news", "news");
}
```

Comment: This has the problem that the server variable isn't available in socket.js. It's being declared in app.js like: var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
  console.log("Express server started!");
});

Comment: @Jorre Check out now. Export the server from `app.js` and require it in `socket.js`.